# Debug Java object attributes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

From my UI, I pass some object attributes to the server.

So I pass an object say 'filter' as below;

```
{
attr1: 'val1',
attr2: 'val2',
attr3: ['val1','val2'],
}
```

My question is while I get this simplistic view of what gets passed on the client-side (using Firebug/Chrome Developer tools), I am looking at a similar thing in the Eclipse Debug View.

I have tried using Watch/Inspect in the Debug view, but it seems to be displaying a lot of additional info which I do not need.

So it displays HashMap as 'table', then says before, after, etc OR in short, I have to keep expanding lot of stuff just to see simple data !!

My question is how do I get to see just the attributes like attr1, attr2, attr3, etc

Comment: You can use `Expressions` view of Eclipse while debugging. In `Expressions` view you can get the value of all your attributes directly e.g. `mayMap.getValue("attr1")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Display view in eclipse. there you can write and evaluate any expression.

This you can enable from Windows-> Show View -> Other -> Search for Display.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Expressions view of Eclipse while debugging. In Expressions view you can get the value of all your attributes directly e.g. mayMap.getValue("attr1")

[image]

Comment: I did check that. Even in the Expressions view, it is quite confusing !!

Comment: For me even if has have value as an object which contains many field, it works. What confuses you ?

Comment: So you have to explicitly say like .get(1), get(2), etc ?

Comment: @testndtv : yes. But you can also get all keys or all values using map's methods.